# Iterate over a comma-separated list in a Google Sheets Cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm working on a Google Sheet and want to automate the process of turning the columns into a custom JSON object.  I have one column in my sheet that is a comma-separated list of strings:

`"apple", "orange", "banana"`

and I want to create an Array field with this.  It's easy to just create an array with `CONCATENATE`:

`=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34), "list", CHAR(34), " : [", A1, "]")`

gives me:

`"list" : ["apple", "orange", "banana"]`

Now I want to turn each item in the list into it's own JSON object.  My desired output is:

```
"list" : [  { "name" : "apple" },
            { "name" : "orange" },
            { "name" : "banana" }
          ]
```

If there's just one item in the cell, this is an easy substitute:

`==SUBSTITUTE("{ name: ''}", "''", A1)`

gives me what I want:

`{ "name" : "apple" }`

But the trick is that I don't know how many items are in the cell to begin with, and I want to `SUBSTITUTE` and `CONCATENATE` for each item.

I've been trying to avoid scripting so far; is it possible to do this with some clever functions?  Or do I need to use scripting to do this now?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A2:A="",,"""list"" : [ "&REGEXREPLACE(
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))<>"", 
 "{ ""name"" : "&SPLIT(A2:A, ",")&" },♦", ))
 ,,999^99))), ",♦$", )&" ♦]"), "♦", CHAR(10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! What a formula!  It works great, though I need to dig in a bit further to understand exactly what's going on... thanks!